# read from memcache in Yii2 when put was from node

Tags: php, node.js, memcached, yii2

We have a Yii2 application. And we use memcache. In our system node.js writes to cache and php reads from cache. But I get the following error in php:

```
MemcachePool::get(): Failed to uncompress data
```

In node memcache module I addedkeyCompression

```
new Memcached(host + ':' + port, {keyCompression: false});
```

But seams like node.js compresses data to memcache and php cannot read it correctly. How to fix that? THanks.

Answer (score 0):

We should set to the memcache data as string, not json or whatever. This solves the issue.